# nodejs 6 installation shows version 0.10.25

Tags: package-management, nodejs, curl

I am trying to install the nodejs 6 version :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

First of all  , it returns me an error:

```
env: -E: No such file or directory
```

but if I ommit the `-E` it runs ok.

And when I install nodejs ,

```
node -v
v0.10.25
```